# What's the difference between flexibleMaxX,flexibleMaxY and widthSizable,heightSizable in Xcode IB editor?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I have 2 `UIViews` in Xcode `storyboard/xib` editor. The good view is created when I create a `XIB` file from **File > New**. The bad view is the one I dragged from the drawer. I'm not able to tell the difference in the attributes, size, identity inspectors but in XML they have slightly different attributes for `autoresizingMask`. What's the difference between `flexibleMaxX`,`flexibleMaxY` and `widthSizable`,`heightSizable`?

```
    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB" userLabel="good">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="164"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="492" y="-643"/>
    </view>
    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="VBH-XW-0HZ" userLabel="bad">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="101"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="492" y="-837.5"/>
    </view>
```

What I noticed is if I replace the original (good) `UIView` with a `UIView` (bad) from the drawer and add my UI elements, the `autolayout/constraint` doesn't seem to work. Not sure if anyone faces this issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!